# Extract XSLT tags without unnecessary namespaces with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

Unfortunately, i'm a newbie to XLST. I couldn't find a matching solution for my problem. I have to transform a file with XSLT 1.0. Given file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:A xsi:schemaLocation="urn:A A.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:A="urn:A">
    <A:B>
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>foo</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
    <A:B>
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>bar</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
</A:A>
```

Wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C xmlns="urn:C">
    <D>foo</D>
</C>
<C xmlns="urn:C">
    <D>bar</D>
</C>
```

I am stuck to get the desired result. My transformer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:A="urn:A">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="A:B">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <A:B xmlns:A="urn:A">
        <C xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>foo</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
    <A:B xmlns:A="urn:A">
        <C xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>bar</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the `A:B` envelope?

Comment: Your own code matches and recreates those `A:B` elements with `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">` so why do you do that instead of just copying or recreating the child nodes and descendants of the `A:B` elements? But stripping some namespaces is always a bit painful in XSLT 1 where there is no `copy-namespaces="no"`.

Comment: I already tried copying, but then the namespaces will remain. I got stuck at the try above because it is almost my desired result except the fact i have this envelope.

Comment: What are the rules to copy in scope namespace and which not to copy? In your result sample you show `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` but it is not used? So other than that example, can you explain which namespaces you want in the result and which ones not?

Comment: You are right: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` is not needed. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE19Q does

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and that way processes only the grandgrandchildren and their descendants with a template that strips all namespaces but the one each element is in.

Comment: Works perfect. How could i add something like a "split line" between each C tag (created xml is then not valid anymore)?

Comment: Can you ask a new question about that? Your original question shows that two top level C elements so there it seems you wanted a result that is not a well-formed document. It is not clear whether your request for a "split line" is meant to have a different but then well-formed result document or a request to change the formatting of the result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228384/add-separator-to-extracted-xslt-tags-with-xslt-1-0