# Add separator to extracted XSLT tags with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am extracting tags from an input file and want to add plain separators between the tags (the xml is then not valid any more). Given file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:A xsi:schemaLocation="urn:A A.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:A="urn:A">
    <A:B>
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>foo</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
    <A:B>
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>bar</D>
        </C>
    </A:B>
</A:A>
```

Wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C xmlns="urn:C">
    <D>foo</D>
</C>
#SEPARATOR#
<C xmlns="urn:C">
    <D>bar</D>
</C>
```

I am stuck to get the desired result. My transformer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>foo</D>
        </C>
    
        <C xmlns="urn:C">
            <D>bar</D>
        </C>
```

Any ideas how to add the `#SEPARATOR#` line?

Comment: Do you not know in advance the names and namespaces of the elements in the input file?

Comment: No, the sheet is used in different scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is too contrived. Perhaps you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">&#10;#SEPARATOR#&#10;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The question is what should the result be when element `C` or any of its descendants has more than one child.

Comment: C can actually have more than one child.

Comment: I made a solution that also works for more childern in any depth. I have prepend ``<xsl:if test="name()='C'">&#10;#SEPARATOR#&#10;</xsl:if>`` before the ``xsl:element``. By this, i will also get a sepator before the very first C tag but that is ok.